# Core Service get Publication parent

Tags: 2011, core-service, blueprint

I'm looking for a solution to get the (BluePrint) parent of a Publication based on its TCM URI, could you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the Core Service `Read` method, to read in the data of a Publication, and check its `Parents` property:

```cs
var pubData = (PublicationData)client.Read("tcm:0-6-1", new ReadOptions());
foreach (var parent in pubData.Parents)
{
    string parentUri = parent.IdRef;
}
```

Please note there can be multiple BluePrint parents for a Publication. You can find the Core Service API guide for 2011 on http://sdltridionworld.com under `downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2011`
([requires login](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/about/access/index.aspx))

Comment: That's all I needed, I'll read the guide, thanks